# i'm having a trouble bridging my object

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

i am having a trouble bridging the edges, the one i know was to selecting the edge i want to merge and then press W as the hotkeys for "bridge edge loops"[image] but somehow the hotkeys doesn't work on me it changing something else instead. ps: i'm using 2.82a version of blender.

Comment: The W menu depends on which selection mode is active. Switch to edge selection mode, then it will appear in the W menu.

Answer (score 0):

In Blender 2.8 the **W** key to open the **Context menu** has been replaced by the **R**ight **M**ouse **B**utton. As it is a **Context menu** you have to be in **Edge select mode** to have the **Bridge Edge Loops** option available.

1. **Edge select** mode.
2. Select the two edges.
3. **RMB** to open the **Context menu**.
4. Choose the **Bridge Edge Loop**.

Another way which works in both vertex or edge select mode is to open the **Edge menu** and select the Bridge Edge Loop option from there.
[image]

Comment: you have resolved my problem, thank you so much for helping me!